# Can't connect to MySQL server on host

Tags: python, android, kivy, pymysql

I have am using pYMYSQL to connect db  and used buildozer to deploy on android device.
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'freedb.tech'
ERROR

---

> 05-14 17:15:20.090    4020    4058    org.test.myapp  I   python  Something went
> wrong: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'freedb.tech' ([Errno
> 7] No address associated with hostname)")

### python file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.animation import Animation
from hoverable import HoverBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
import json, glob
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import random
import pymysql.cursors

db_string = "postgresql://[user]:[password]@ec2-54-197-100-79.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d4bsdrtg9i2j5d"
Builder.load_file('design.kv')


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def sign_up(self):
        self.manager.current = "sign_up_screen"

    def login(self, uname, pword):
        with open("users.json") as file:
            users = json.load(file)
        if uname in users and users[uname]['password'] == pword:
            self.manager.current = 'login_screeen_success'
        else:
            anim = Animation(color=(0.6, 0.7, 0.1, 1))
            anim.start(self.ids.login_wrong)
            self.ids.login_wrong.text = "Wrong username or password!"


class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass


class SignUpScreen(Screen):
    def add_user(self, uname, pword):
        with open("users.json") as file:
            users = json.load(file)

        users[uname] = {'username': uname, 'password': pword,
                        'created': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")}

        with open("users.json", 'w') as file:
            json.dump(users, file)

        self.manager.current = "sign_up_screen_success"


class SignUpScreenSuccess(Screen):
    def go_to_login(self):
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        self.manager.current = "login_screen"


class LoginScreenSuccess(Screen):
    def log_out(self):
        self.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        self.manager.current = "login_screen"

    def get_quote(self, feel):
        feel = feel.lower()
        available_feelings = glob.glob("quotes/*txt")

        available_feelings = [Path(filename).stem for filename in
                              available_feelings]

        if feel in available_feelings:
            with open(f"quotes/{feel}.txt", encoding='utf8') as file:
                quotes = file.readlines()
            self.ids.quote.text = random.choice(quotes)
        else:
            self.ids.quote.text = "Try another feeling"

    def feed_back(self):
        self.manager.current = "feedback_screen"


class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, HoverBehavior, Image):
    pass


class FeedbackScreen(Screen):
    def send_feed(self, feed):
        print(feed)
        # connection = psycopg2.connect(user="[user]",
        #                               password="[password]",
        #                               host="ec2-54-197-100-79.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
        #                               port="5432",
        #                               database="d4bsdrtg9i2j5d")
        # db = create_engine(db_string)
        #
        # postgres_insert_query = """INSERT INTO feed(feed_info) VALUES (%s)"""
        #
        # db.execute(postgres_insert_query, feed)
        # print("Record inserted successfully into feed table")
        try:

            mydb = pymysql.connect(
                host="freedb.tech",
                user="freedbtech_reds",
                password="Raskol@786",
                database="freedbtech_redsdb"
            )

            mycursor = mydb.cursor()

            sql = "INSERT INTO feed (feed_info) VALUES (%s)"
            val = (feed,)
            mycursor.execute(sql, val)
            mydb.commit()
            print(mycursor.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully into feed table")

            self.manager.current = 'login_screen'
        except pymysql.Error as err:
            print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()


---------------------------------
buildozer spec
--------------------------------
requirements = python3,kivy,PyMySQL
```

Comment: I hope these are not your real credentials.

Comment: Its working fine in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

your saying that these credentials are correct but your still can't connect to database
this is simple problem
**Note:-**

> if you don't have internet access you get this error also

so to get internet access **You have to add `android.permissions = INTERNET` in your buildozer.spec file**

Happy coding (^_^)